# Taylor polynomial for second order differential

Tags: taylor-expansion, differential

I have an exercise, I have to determine the Taylor polynomial for second order differential in a certain point for a few functions. The problem is if I compute the second order differential in the given point, I am left with no variables, so I can't apply Taylor for it. Or I'm doing something wrong.

For example for $~f(x,y)=\arctan(x/y),~~~ x>0~$ in point $(1,1)$

I would appreciate if someone could explain a method to solve it or give an example, thank you!

Comment: I do not understand the language in your question. Are you not trying to compute the Taylor polynomial of degree $2$ of $f$ at the point $(1,1)$?

Comment: Second degree, yes, sorry. But with the formula that we have for 2nd degree differential equation and after I compute it in that point (1,1), I'm left with something like: (constant)dx^2+2*(constant)dxdy+(constant)dy^2, so I can't compute Taylor for something without variables. Or I don't know how to

Comment: I don't know why you're talking about differential equations. You need to compute second-order partial derivatives at the point $(1,1)$. There are ways to work with Taylor series of the first partial derivatives, too, I suppose.

Comment: That's what the exercise says, I just translated, but it does say 2nd degree differential. Probably our professor messed up the terminology. We did a Taylor expansion for 2nd degree, but not in a certain point and it worked. Not sure how we are supposed to do this though

Comment: It would be helpful for our understanding of what it is you’re trying to ask if you showed your work so far in your question.